# How do I solve this array problem in C language?

Tags: arrays, c, for-loop, nested-loops, variable-length-array

I have 2 arrays:
`int element[3] = {0, 1, 2};`
`int quantity[3] = {2, 3, 4};`
Now I want a result array that will have two zeros, three ones and four twos.
`int result[2+3+4] = {0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2};`
How do I do this using loop?

Comment: A good start would be to calculate the size of the new `result` array. Then perhaps a loop over the `element` array. And inside that loop, a loop using the corresponding value from `quantity`.

Comment: "... and a partridge in a pear tree..." `:-)` ... Seriously, `realloc()` could be used to achieve this with a single loop growing the array (and a trivial inner loop poking repetitions of a value into its elements.) Hint: `realloc( NULL, n );` acts just like `malloc( n )`... Start with 0 and work your way up to the completed array.

Comment: @Jabberwocky You have the elements and their quantity. Now produce the resulting array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to count the number of elements in the result array and to declare either a variable length array with the calculated value or to allocate dynamically such an array.

For example

```
int quantity[3] = {2, 3, 4};

size_t n = 0;
for ( size_t i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
{
    n += quantity[i];
}

int result[n];

// or
// int *result = malloc( n * sizeof( int ) );
```

And then in nested loops you need fill the resulted array.

For example

```
for ( size_t i = 0, j = 0; i < 3; i++ )
{
    for ( size_t k = 0; k < quantity[i]; k++ )
    {
        result[j++] = element[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: "And then in nested loops you need fill the resulted array.".  But how?

Comment: @MinBaniAdam See my appended answer.

Comment: 'result[j++] = element[i];' should be  'result[j] = element[i];' and then j++;

Comment: @MinBaniAdam If you want to write two statements instead of one statement you can do that.:)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly we need to calculate the size of the result array. Then start populating your result array each element at a time. While we populate the result array, we need to increment the index.

```
int elementSize = sizeof(element)/sizeof(element[0]);
int resultSize = 0;

//pre calculating the size of result array
for(int i=0;i<elementSize;i++ ) {
    resultSize += quantity[i];
}

int result[resultSize], currIndex = 0;
//picking each element
for(int i = 0;i< elementSize; i++ ) {
    int currElement = element[i];
    int currQuantity = quantity[i];

//filling the current element required no of times in the result array
    while(currQuantity--) {
        result[currIndex] = currElement;
        currIndex++;
    }
}

//just a for loop to check the elements inside result array
for(int i=0;i<resultSize;i++)
    printf("%d\n",result[i]);
```

Comment: You are using C++

Comment: just a minor change if using C. For checking the elements inside result array, use printf instead of cout. ```printf("%d\n",result[i]);```

Edited my answer, thanks for pointing out.